# In JBOSS 7 can war file access a jar file located in ear/lib instead of web-inf/lib

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, classloader, jboss-modules

I have project structure like below

`SOME-EAR/`
----- `sampleWarOne.war`
----- `sampleWarTwo.war`

inside `SOME-EAR` I have lib folder `SOME-EAR/lib`. Is it possible to use jars present in `SOME-EAR/lib` ? As of now I am picking from `WEB-INF/lib`, but some of the jars are used in multiple war files. So I wanted to pick it from `SOME-EAR/lib` instead.

How do I pick from `SOME-EAR/lib` instead ?

Comment: did you try using ear/lib to see if it works?

Comment: I tried with class-path approach and did not worked. Can you give an example on how to use it ? thanks

Comment: Is your project using Maven?

Answer (score 1):

You can find [JBoss AS 7 Classloading](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7) documentation useful.

Just put all your common jars in EAR's /lib dir and **set ear-subdeployments-isolated to false**

Should do the trick **unless** you're trying to load **e.g.: taglib libraries**

Comment: Please upvote an answer if it helped you in some way. Accept the one that you followed to resolve your problem. That's how this community works!